# Can I somehow elegantly forbid using unsingned variables in my template function?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Consider this piece of code:

```
template <typename T>
T abs(const T& n)
{
    if (!std::is_signed<T>::value)
        throw logic_error;
    if (n < 0)
        return -n;
    return n;
}
```

I want to completely forbid the usage of my function with `unsigned` variables, since it doesn't make sense, and probably the user doesn't even know that he uses an `unsigned` variable. For example, I can somewhat avoid this problem:

```
template <typename T>
T abs(const T& n)
{
    if constexpr(!std::is_signed<T>::value)
        n += "";
    if (n < 0)
        return -n;
    return n;
}
```

But if I call `abs(4u)`, the compiler errors are not very obvious. Something like `"can't apply += const char[1] to double"`. Can I make it somehow more obvious? Or just make multiple overloads?

Comment: If not signed just static assert with a message?

Comment: One solution is also to do: `template <typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T>::value>::type* = nullptr> T abs(const T& n)`. OR as a return type `typename std::enable_if<std::is_signed<T>::value, T>::type
abs(const T& n)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### 1. concepts

Since C++20 you can use concepts for this.

If you are fine with integer only parameters you could use [`std::signed_integral`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/signed_integral):

```cpp
#include <concepts>

template <std::signed_integral T>
T abs(const T& n)
{
    if (n < 0)
        return -n;
    return n;
}
```

If you want to also allow `double`, etc... you'd have to make your own concept:

```cpp
template<class T>
concept signed_value = std::is_signed_v<T>;

template <signed_value T>
T abs(const T& n)
{
    if (n < 0)
        return -n;
    return n;
}
```

This would result in a compiler error like this if you try to use an unsigned type:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'abs(unsigned int&)'
note: candidate: 'template<class T>  requires  signed_integral<T> T abs(const T&)'
```

Which makes it very clear that `abs()` only accepts signed types from just the signature.

---

##### 2. SFINAE

If C++20 is not available, you could use SFINAE, although the error messages you would get are quite cryptic:

```cpp
template <class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_signed_v<T>, T> abs(const T& n)
{
    std::cout << "HELLO" << std::endl;
    if (n < 0)
        return -n;
    return n;
}
```

But this would result in an error message like this:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'abs(unsigned int&)'
note: candidate: 'template<class T> std::enable_if_t<is_signed_v<T>, T> abs(const T&)'
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
    In substitution of 'template<bool _Cond, class _Tp> using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if::type [with bool _Cond = false; _Tp = unsigned int]':
    required by substitution of 'template<class T> std::enable_if_t<is_signed_v<T>, T> abs2(const T&) [with T = unsigned int]'
```

So, you need to be comfortable with SFINAE errors for this one.

---

##### 3. good old `static_assert`

Alternatively, you could also just add a `static_assert` to your function.
This won't be visible in the declaration at all though, only in the definition of the function.

```cpp
template <class T>
T abs(const T& n)
{
    static_assert(std::is_signed_v<T>, "T must be signed!");
    if (n < 0)
        return -n;
    return n;
}
```

---

##### 4. using [`std::abs()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs)

C++ already provides a `std::abs()` implementation that handles all the potential edge cases for you, so if you can, I would recommend using that one instead.

Your code also contains a potential bug if you pass in the minimum value for a given int type, e.g. `INT_MIN`.

- The smallest value a 32bit int can represent is -2147483648
- But the largest it can represent is only 2147483647

So, a call to your `abs()` function with the minimal value, e.g. `abs(-2147483648)` would result in **undefined behaviour** (`std::abs()` has the same behaviour, but it's still worth pointing out).

Answer (score 5):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
T abs(T n)
{
  static_assert(std::is_signed<T>::value, "Type must be signed.");
  if (n < 0) { return -n; }
  return n;
}

int main()
{
    return abs(3u);
}
```